# Python Insert variables in string

Tags: python

In python I have a below string

```
body='{"mode":"sync","message":"43b","messages":[{"node1":44,"node2":45}]}'
```

I need to replace the hard coded values `44` and `45` with variables `v1` and `v2`.

I tried using format option, but didnt seem to work

Comment: What did you try and what didn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need string formatting:

```
>>> v1 = 44
>>> v2 = 45
>>> body='{"mode":"sync","message":"43b","messages":[{"node1":%s,"node2":%s}]}' % (v1, v2)
'{"mode":"sync","message":"43b","messages":[{"node1":40,"node2":45}]}'
```

Comment: Glad to help. Please accept the answer if it worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module:

```
import json

body = '{"mode":"sync","message":"43b","messages":[{"node1":44,"node2":45}]}'
j = json.loads(body)

v1 = "foo"
v2 = "bar"

j["messages"][0]["node1"] = v1
j["messages"][0]["node2"] = v2

print(json.dumps(j))
```

Output:

```
{"mode": "sync", "message": "43b", "messages": [{"node2": "bar", "node1": "foo"}]}
```

Comment: good to see that im not the only one, who thinks that json is the right way :)

Comment: thanks for the response.

Answer (score 1):

you can convert this string to dict, and then you can replace it like this:

```
body='{"mode":"sync","message":"43b","messages":[{"node1":44,"node2":45}]}'
import json
body = json.loads(body)
print body
v1 = "aaa"
v2 = "bbb"
body["messages"][0]["node1"] = v1
body["messages"][0]["node2"] = v2
body = json.dumps(body)
print body
```

result:

> {"message": "43b", "messages": [{"node1": "aaa", "node2": "bbb"}],
>   "mode": "sync"}

Answer (score -2):

```
v1 = 44
v2 = 45
body='{"mode":"sync","message":"43b","messages":[{"node1":%s,"node2":%s}]}' % (v1, v2)
```

use `%d` instead of `%s` if you want a TypeError to be raised if v1 and/or v2 are not integers.

Comment: thanks for the response.